# Template working with std::string and char []

Tags: c++, string, templates

I wrote a function to trim strings. I want to use it with std::string and char[] type. I used template. When I use my function with string type everything is good, but I can't use it with char []. My code is below:

```
template<typename T, typename Predicate>
T trimString(const T& str, Predicate pred) {
    auto left = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), pred);
    auto right = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), pred);
    return T(left, right.base());
}


int main() {
    std::string text = "      123 example      ";
    //char text[] = "      123 example      ";
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    std::cout << trimString(text, isspace) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I use it with char [] I have this errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "trimString" matches the argument list Task3.exe
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2672   'trimString': no matching overloaded function found
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "trimString" matches the argument list Task3.exe
```

Comment: Arrays don't have properties `.begin()` and `.end()`. You can use `std::begin` and `std::end` instead. `T` is a `char[]`. A function can't return an array. What do you expect `trimString` to return for a C-string? Can you write the function without a template?

Comment: Why do you _want_ to use it with `char[]`?  It is trivial to construct a `std::string` from that.

Comment: @jabaa mind turning you comment into an answer?

Comment: You cannot return a fixed size char array by value; you'd need a wrapper like `std::array<char, ...>`; note through that you wouldn't be able to adjust the size of the returned object based on the contents in this scenario. You may want to create a template taking a first parameter of type `std::string_view` and simply return a `std::string` in all cases...

Comment: @TheDreamsWind The question is unclear. Is the question, why does it not work or is the question, how to solve it. My comment answers, why it doesn't work, but it doesn't answer, how to solve it. I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding why your code doesn't compile, your actual *design problem* is here:

```
return T(...
```

If you take a type `char[10]` and trim 2 off the front, do you want to return a `char[10]`? No, you do not. You want to return *eight* chars.

That is to say, it doesn't matter whether you are called with a `std::string`, a `std::string_view`, a `std::array<char,N>`, a `std::span<char,-1>`, a `std::vector<char>` or a `char[N]`, you always want to return a char buffer whose size can only be determined at runtime when you actually know how much was trimmed away.

Conveniently, C++ *has* a dynamically sized char buffer, it's called `std::string`.

So it would be best to change

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Predicate>
T trimString(const T &str, Predicate pred)
{
    auto left = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), pred);
    auto right = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), pred);
    return T(left, right.base());
}
```

into

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Predicate>
std::string trimString(const T &str, Predicate pred)
{
    auto left = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), pred);
    auto right = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), pred);
    return std::string(left, right.base());
}
```

...except.

Except - you're writing this as a template, so your code can work on multiple types of char buffers. And then, you are immediately calling `.begin`, so it only works on char buffers that implement `.begin`.

Thankfully, this is a *solved problem* - you are not the first person who thought that we could generalize over different types of char buffer:

```cpp
template<typename Predicate>
std::string trimString(std::string_view str, Predicate pred)
{
    auto left = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), pred);
    auto right = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), pred);
    return std::string(left, right.base());
}
```

That should solve the whole of the design problem. (Whether the internals of the function work, I haven't checked.)